# Why won't subprocess.run take a list of arguments?

Tags: python, list, subprocess, python-3.7

I am running a script called `mini_medsmaker.py`, and in that script I am using subprocess.run to call another script called `mini_mocks.py`.

I am using argparse to list my arguments, and this is the command I am running:

```
subprocess.run(["python", "/path/to/mini_mocks.py", *vars(args).values()])
```

Whenever I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/work/mccleary_group/vassilakis.g/superbit-metacal/superbit_lensing/medsmaker/scripts/mini_medsmaker.py", line 86, in <module>
    rc = main(args)
  File "/work/mccleary_group/vassilakis.g/superbit-metacal/superbit_lensing/medsmaker/scripts/mini_medsmaker.py", line 81, in main
    subprocess.run(["python", "/work/mccleary_group/vassilakis.g/superbit-metacal/superbit_lensing/medsmaker/scripts/mini_mocks.py", *vars(args).values()])
  File "/work/mccleary_group/vassilakis.g/miniconda3/envs/sbclone2/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/work/mccleary_group/vassilakis.g/miniconda3/envs/sbclone2/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/work/mccleary_group/vassilakis.g/miniconda3/envs/sbclone2/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1482, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

However, I thought `subprocess.run` could take lists as an object? How can I fix this?

I have tried converting it to both a JSON and a string, but then my mini_mocks.py file can't take it as an argument.

Comment: Yes, it can take a list. But it has to be a list of strings. Something in `vars(args).values()` is a list, not a string.

Comment: It looks like you truncated the error message and that the message doesn't reference the single line of code you've posted. Please post the full error message, and to help debug, add `print([*vars(args).values()])` so we can see the data.

Comment: Just put the full error message in, let me try and get you the printed args

Comment: Add what is `args` - is it a class?

Comment: Here is where I add the args:
    `parser.add_argument('--mock_dir', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--exposure_list', type=list)
    parser.add_argument('--outfile', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-outdir', type=str, 
    parser.add_argument('-fname_base', action='store', type=str, 
    parser.add_argument('-run_name', action='store', type=str, 
    parser.add_argument('--meds_coadd', action='store_true',\
    parser.add_argument('--overwrite', action='store_true'
    parser.add_argument('--exposures_per_list', type=int
    return parser.parse_args()`

Comment: You seem to assume that `vars` will enumerate the parameters in `args` in a certain way, but I don't see where that is documented to be the case.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`subprocess.run` does support a list of arguments, however if the list contains anything more than a string, bytes or `os.PathLike` objects it would fail at:

```py
# subprocess.py: line 608 in the list2cmdline function

for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
    bs_buf = []
```

Because the [`os.fsdecode`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-fsdecode-method/) method only gets a filename in the form of strings, bytes or `os.PathLike` as mentioned above, and returns the decoded filename. Here you are trying to map every `value` of the `vars(...)` dictionary, and some of the values are lists (and maybe more unwanted types such as functions etc..) which the `fsdecode` cannot execute upon.

---

Make sure that you refine each value in  `*vars(A).values()` such that only the mentioned types above are in:

```py
subprocess.run(["python", "./your_path.py", *filter(lambda x: type(x) in [str, bytes, os.PathLike], vars(args).values())])
```

Or if you want the literal string of the list:

```
subprocess.run(["python", "./your_path.py", *map(str, vars(args).values())])
```

Comment: running your filter that you gave me allowed me to pass the arguments into the next script finally. Now got another error of the same type but that's a problem with the different script, but this answer solves my initial problem of passing the arguments through!

Comment: @GeorgeVassilakis well, that's another problem on its own and should be opened as a separate question :-)

Comment: Just converting everything to strings is an odd solution. So a list becomes a python string representation of a list and a flag becomes "True"? Never mind that everything is now positional arguments without any concern about the order they've been passed. This may keep the program from crashing on this call, but its hard to see how it actually works.

Comment: @tdelaney The OP did not specify how these parameters are used and for what reason. I gave the "convert everything to string" as a side-solution, not knowing what really the intention, although it seems from first impression that the OP wants every dictionary value to be passed, regardless of its type.